# How I can pass multiple parameters to URL in php

Tags: php, url, parameters

I have a problem in passing 2 parameters via URL
I don't know how, so I wrote this:

```
<form method="get" >
   <b>Enter the Quantity you want:</b>
   <input type="text" name="quantity">
</form>

<br><br>

<a href='./shopping-cart.php?part_id="<?php echo $_GET['part_id']; ?>"&quantity="<?php echo $_GET['quantity']; ?>"'>
   <img src="add_to_shopping_cart.png">
</a>
```

`$_GET['part_id']` this var from another URL and I want to pass it again and `$_GET['quantity']` quantity from form.

Comment: In your form add `<input type="hidden" name="part_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['part_id']; ?>"/>`

Comment: Are you sure that the link begins with `./`?

Comment: ok I will but what about the url code is it correct ??

Comment: yes ,the problem in the parameters in the link

Comment: Your form should also have an `action` attribute. And there might be a problem with the quotes.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: quantity in C:\wamp\www\...

Comment: @black I guess the above `html` code is two separate files? The first one passes the quantity to the other? If not, then you should check that `$_GET` variables exist.

Comment: I get the product_id from page (catalog.php) then in page product.php
I get the p_id from URL and retrieve product information
after that the user will enter quantity he/she want and click on shopping cart image and quantity ,product_id will pass throw the URL

Comment: @black Check my answer for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this notice *Undefined index: quantity* cause you are trying to access an undefined variable. 
If your page url is something like `page_name.php?quantity=5` then `$_GET['quantity]` is set, otherwise it isn't.

You should check if the `$_GET` variable exist.
If so, use @user4035 answer to print the url.

```
if(isset($_GET['quantity']))
{ 
    //html code,the url
    //echo $_GET['quantity']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode) function for your parameters, and don't use the double quotes:

```
<a href='./shopping-cart.php?part_id=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['part_id']); ?>&quantity=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['quantity']); ?>'>
```

Even though, I suggest you to avoid long urls and use POST with hidden fields.

Comment: thank you for your help but I still have the same problem (
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: quantity in C:\wamp\www)

Comment: @black This notice means, that $_GET['quantity'] element is undefined. It has nothing to do with the link. To avoid the notice, use the yannis hristofakis suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few errors that I can see.

You can't use `$_GET['quantity']` if the user is entering it in without reloading the page (Remember, PHP is not client-side). Thus, I suggest using JavaScript for that.

Javascript:

```
function buildUrl(a) {
   var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value; 
   a.href = "./shopping-cart.php?part_id="+<?php echo $_GET['part_id']; ?>
   +"&quantity="+qty;
}
```

As you no longer need to get a PHP variable from the current page, the form is obsolete and a simple link will do.

HTML:

```
<b>Enter the Quantity you want:</b>
<input type="text" name="quantity">
<a href='#' onclick="buildUrl(this);"> //onclick attribute triggers the JavaScript
    <img src="add_to_shopping_cart.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Could I have an explanation as to why I was down-voted?

Comment: Although you answer is very good,I think you shouldn't point him to a client side solution. He is missing fundamentally things such as POST-GET request,and an answer such as your will only make things more difficult for him. Consider that he might don't even know `javascript`. If you think my vote is unjustified you can edit you answer and I will undo.

Comment: @yannishristofakis that's a fair point, I'll leave it up though in case someone would like to try it this way.